# How to enable/disable a kubernetes scheduler plugin?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

I want to disable a Kubernetes scheduler plugin. [The kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/) says to use a configuration file like:

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration
profiles:
  - plugins:
      score:
        disabled:
        - name: NodeResourcesLeastAllocated
        enabled:
        - name: MyCustomPluginA
          weight: 2
        - name: MyCustomPluginB
          weight: 1
```

But it does not say how to activate this config file. I've tried calling `kube-scheduler --conf conf.yaml` locally on my computer but do not understand if the kube-scheduler should be run from inside the kube scheduling pod. I'm using minkube with kubernetes v1.20.2.

Comment: the doc does mention this command: `kube-scheduler --config <filename>`, you could try this as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same result as with kube-scheduler --conf.

Comment: @HissPirat Could you please show the exact command that you have used?

Answer (score 2):

I found an issue on github discussing the documentation, I posted how we managed to configure plugins in that thread https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/21128 .